# Dell m3800 with QHD - No 1920x1080

Tags: fedora

Normally I am working on two FullHD 27" screens, but when I am in school i need to use my laptop display with QHD.

But seriously, who can work with 3200x1080 on a 15" display? :D

My Windows VM can display FullHD on the laptop, but Fedora 21. My question now: Is there any graphical driver for Fedora 21 or do i have to create a "custom" solution?

Answer (score 0):

Same for me. On a 13" screen!
Solved by growing the hidpi scaling factor to 2 (GNOME tweak cool)
GNOME is OK, but still to small for some stuff:
Grub
Text console => mitigated by setfont sun12x22 
Google chrome => need to zoom constantly
Firefox idem

Dell xps 13 2015 laptop with qhd screen